# hasOptionalKeyword in FieldDescriptor not working in PHP

Tags: php, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use the `FieldDescriptor` class in my PHP project, and try to determine which fields of the protobuf message are optional. I'm using the `hasOptionalKeyword` function on the `Google\Protobuf\FieldDescriptor` class
but i'm running into the following error:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "hasOptionalKeyword" of class "Google\Protobuf\Internal\FieldDescriptor".
```

It seems the `hasOptionalKeyword` function calls the internal descriptor with the same `hasOptionalKeyword` function, but that function is not implemented in the internal class.

I'm using the package `google/protobuf` version `3.23`

Anything I am missing?